# Use uploaded image as banner header for custom theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Right now I have a div with a width of 100% and height of 200px as a placeholder for where a custom banner would be. How can I add an uploaded image as the banner itself, instead of a placeholder div?

This is for a custom wordpress theme.

Comment: You mean you want users to be able to upload an image to be used as a header or you just don't know how to add it to the template?

Comment: @Aibrean i want to be able to upload an image and use that as a banner inside of the header.php. I don't want this to be a template thing, because its a custom theme

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers